# How can I get my firebase listener to load data to my redux state in a React Native app so I can read the data within my ComponentDidMount function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux

I am trying to load a notification token (`notificationToken`) that I've stored within Firebase to a React Native component.

Once the `notificationToken` is loaded to my redux state, I want to check for my device permissions to see if the `notificationToken` has expired within the function `getExistingPermission()` that I run in the `componentDidMount()`.

If the token has expired, then I'll replace the token within Firebase with the new token.  If it's the same, then nothing happens (which is intended functionality).

When I'm running my function `getExistingPermission()` to check if the token is up-to-date the Firebase listener that pulls the `notificationToken` does not load in time, and so it's always doing a write to the Firebase database with a 'new' token.

I'm pretty sure using `async`/`await` would solve for this, but have not been able to get it to work.  **Any idea how I can ensure that the `notificationToken` loads from firebase to my redux state first before I run any functions within my `componentDidMount()` function?**  Code below - thank you!

## src/screens/Dashboard.js

*Should I use a `.then()` or `async`/`await` operator to ensure the notificationToken loads prior to running it through the `getExistingPermission()` function?*

```
import {
  getExistingPermission
} from '../components/Notifications/NotificationFunctions';

componentDidMount = async () => {
        // Listener that loads the user, reminders, contacts, and notification data
        this.unsubscribeCurrentUserListener = currentUserListener((snapshot) => {
          try {
            this.props.watchUserData();
          } catch (e) {
            this.setState({ error: e, });
          }
        });
        if (
          !getExistingPermission(
            this.props.notificationToken, //this doesn't load in time
            this.props.user.uid)
          ) {
          this.setState({ showNotificationsModal: true });
        }
      };
```

## src/components/Notifications/NotificationFunctions.js

*The problem is probably not here*

```
export const getExistingPermission = async (
  notificationToken,
  uid,
) => {
  const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.askAsync(
    Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
  );
  if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
    console.log('status not granted');
    return false;
  } else {
    let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
    /* compare to the firebase token; if it's the same, do nothing,
    if it's different, replace */
    if (token === notificationToken) {
      console.log('existing token loaded');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('token: ' + token);
      console.log('notificationToken: ' + notificationToken);
      console.log('token is not loading, re-writing token to firebase');
      writeNotificationToken(uid, token);
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```

## src/actions/actions.js

```
// Permissions stuff
watchPermissions = (uid) => (
  (dispatch) => {
    getPermissions(uid + '/notificationToken', (snapshot) => {
      try {
        dispatch(loadNotificationToken(Object.values([snapshot.val()])[0]));
      }
      catch (error) {
        dispatch(loadNotificationToken(''));

        // I could call a modal here so this can be raised at any point of the flow
      }
    });
  }
);

// User Stuff
export const watchUserData = () => (
  (dispatch) => {
    currentUserListener((user) => {
      if (user !== null) {
        console.log('from action creator: ' + user.displayName);
        dispatch(loadUser(user));
        dispatch(watchReminderData(user.uid));  //listener to pull reminder data
        dispatch(watchContactData(user.uid));  //listener to pull contact data
        dispatch(watchPermissions(user.uid));  //listener to pull notificationToken
      } else {
        console.log('from action creator: ' + user);
        dispatch(removeUser(user));
        dispatch(logOutUser(false));
        dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }));
      }
    });
  }
);

export const loadNotificationToken = (notificationToken) => (
  {
    type: 'LOAD_NOTIFICATION_TOKEN',
    notificationToken,
  }
);
```

Comment: can you just move your check to `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` so you can check `if(!prevProps.notificationToken && this.props.notificationToken)`?

Comment: Yes, this worked - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tony gave me the answer.  Needed to move the permissions check to `componentDidUpdate()`.  For those having a similar issue, the component looks like this:

## src/screens/Dashboard.js

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    if (!prevProps.notificationToken && this.props.notificationToken) {
      if (!getExistingPermission(
        this.props.notificationToken,
        this.props.user.uid
      )) {
        this.setState({ showNotificationsModal: true });
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at redux subscribers for this: https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#subscribe .  I implement a subscriber to manage a small state machine like STATE1_DO_THIS, STATE2_THEN_DO_THAT and store that state in redux and use it to render your component.  Only the subscriber should change those states.  That gives you a nice way to handle tricky flows where you want to wait on action1 finishing before doing action2.  Does this help?

Comment: So the answer that I posted works in this situation.  It looks like what you're mentioning would work (although I haven't implemented yet).  What's the difference between using `subscribe` and using the `componentDidUpdate` function?